# How to keep a play button icon centered on an image when screen size is reduced?

Tags: html, css

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Example of problem]

I used the instructions from this tutorial to learn how to put a play button over animated GIFs: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/on-click-animated-gif/

For the most part this works but I'm having trouble getting the play button to stay centered when the screen size changes to mobile.

I am using this theme (Hugo): https://github.com/tomanistor/osprey

I'm guessing I need to contain the image and play button icon in a table or something? The tutorial's example has the images contained in a DIV but when I try that, I lose the play button:

```
<div class="demo-content">
<figure>
<img src="/images/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="Static Image" data-alt="/images/animated-gif.gif">
</figure>
</div>
```

[image: Example of missing play icon]

I'm currently using the following to get both the placeholder and play image:

```
<figure>
<img src="/images/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="Static Image" data-alt="/images/animated-gif.gif">
</figure>
```

I have tried opening my browser's dev tools and playing around with the styles' values but it feels like whack-a-mole.

Here is a snippet of the CSS that I have added to the theme:

```
.
.
.
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-awesome';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format("truetype")
}
.
.
.
figure {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
figure:before,
figure:after {
  position: absolute;
}
figure:before {
  top: 206px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 209, 217, 0.3);
  font-family: 'font-awesome';
  content: '\f04b';
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 95px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #182230;
}
figure:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #656D78;
  background-color: rgba(170, 178, 189, 0.1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.play:before {
  display: none;
}
figure.play:after {
  content: 'playing';
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212121;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figcaption {
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8d9bad;
}
figcaption a {
  color: #59687b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

How can I get my play button to stay exactly centered like in the tutorial example?

Comment: A more general question could be: "how to center with CSS?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `figure:before` to `top: 50%` to keep it 50% from the top, then remove your `margin-left` and use `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` instead, which will move the element to the left and up 50% of it's own width/height. `margin-left: -50px` is the same as `translateX(-50%)` in your example, but using `transform: translate()` is simpler.

```
figure:before {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* margin-left: -50px; */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(204, 209, 217, 0.3);
    font-family: 'font-awesome';
    content: '\f04b';
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 95px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #182230;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```